Do innate spells cost spell slots in 5e?
I'm wondering if innate spells like a Yuan-Ti's animal friendship need spell slots.
I've searched through PHB and MoTM and haven't found anything on the subject.

Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.
